# Olfactory disability put in words

Tags: word-choice

I just saw a joke that made me think.

- Disability regarding sight: blindness (being blind)
- Disability regarding hearing: deafness (being deaf)
- Disability regarding smell: ??? (being ???)

What would that be called?

As a bonus question - what would be the equivalent for all the remaining two senses?

Comment: The closest thing for touch is just anesthesia... there is a genetic condition that makes you not able to feel when you're touching anything or pain but it doesn't have a name in the same sense as the others because it's extremely rare.

Comment: @Catija A fellow of mine argued that *numbness* and *being numb* are the equivalent for the sensory sense (touching) but I feel it's not quite right. It'll do if one must say something but it lacks the exact spot-on-ness I prefer to aim at. What's your take on it?

Comment: Numbness is a lack of sense of touch but, as a native AmE speaker, I only relate it to feelings that have been impeded by anesthesia or the cold... or a part of my body "falling asleep"... it also can be used in the sense of emotional numbness... in which case, it's more figurative. "I felt numb after my father died and couldn't grieve for weeks".

Comment: @Catija Interesting remark that discriminates between two aspects I haven't considered before. You speak of two different kinds of a sensory disability - one that's impeded on oneself intentionally/artificially, while the other is inborn/inherent. Or does the distinction lie in different factors?

Answer (score 7):

There are terms for this but they are the medical terms used by doctors and aren't commonly known by the average person. I don't believe that there's a term that's as well known as "deafness" or "blindness" because these conditions are not nearly as common (or overtly noticeable) to others. What I mean by this is, blindness or deafness impede a person's ability to interact with others in standard ways. Being unable to smell or taste wouldn't be as impactful.

[Being unable to feel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_sensory_and_autonomic_neuropathy), as I said in a comment, is extremely uncommon and only has a medical name associated with a specific condition. The terms below are more general and apply to anyone with the lack of a sense, regardless of the cause.

[anosmia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosmia)

> Anosmia (/ænˈɒzmiə/) is the inability to perceive odor or a lack of functioning olfaction. Anosmia may be temporary, but traumatic anosmia can be permanent. Anosmia is due to an inflammation of the nasal mucosa, blockage of nasal passages or a destruction of one temporal lobe. Inflammation is due to chronic mucosa changes in the paranasal sinus lining and the middle and superior turbinates. Since anosmia causes inflammatory changes in the nasal passageways, it is treated by simply reducing the presence of inflammation.

[ageusia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageusia)

> Ageusia (/əˈɡjuːziə/ ə-GEW-zee-ə) is the loss of taste functions of the tongue, particularly the inability to detect sweetness, sourness, bitterness, saltiness, and umami (meaning "pleasant/savory taste"). It is sometimes confused with anosmia – a loss of the sense of smell. Because the tongue can only indicate texture and differentiate between sweet, sour, bitter, salty, and umami, most of what is perceived as the sense of taste is actually derived from smell. True ageusia is relatively rare compared to hypogeusia – a partial loss of taste – and dysgeusia – a distortion or alteration of taste.

Comment: This is good one. But then, these are medical jargon. There's also *'dysomia'* I wonder OP is asking for general terms that I'm afraid we don't have. +1 anyway! :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure they're very rare and it's not likely they have "common" names.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I have a feeling that with the structure of the word *anosmia* that an educated English speaker would pick up the meaning from context fairly easily.  I actually use this word when I talk to my chemistry students about how to smell chemicals safely.  Anosmia is not particularly rare; it's more common than blindness or deafness, but most people don't realize they have it.  (~1% of the population to some degree)

Answer (score 1):

The condition in which the person has no sense of smell is called *anosmia* and the people with this condition are called *anosmic*.